# Json convert TimeSpan Error .Net Core 2.2

Tags: json, .net-core, timespan, converters, iso8601

i work with .net core 2.2, i tried to deserialize datas from WebApi but TimeSpan Type is not converted.

My InnerException is :{"Could not cast or convert from **System.String to System.TimeSpan.**"}

My ErrorMessage is :{"
**Error converting value "PT20H20M"** to type 'System.TimeSpan'. Path 'value[0].StartTime', line 1, position 179."}

the problem is on a member of my class:
**public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }**

Can someone get the same error or can someone give me some ideas to how manage the problem.

Thanks !

Comment: Please, show us your code and data

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess the error is that the default converter does not know the format that you are trying to send in. You have to use a format that it understands or use a custom converter or use a string and convert it yourself afterwards.

If you run `TimeSpan.Parse("PT20H20M")` you will get an error that says it's not a valid format.

It seems that this call can get you a `TimeSpan`:

```
System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan("P2DT01H")
```

You can use a custom converter as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to) (First one is for .net core 3).

Comment: Thank you IIya .  "PT20H20M" is  ISO8601's duration format which  is a convention to represent dates or periods. my datas have " 20:20 " representation in SQL Server.      what do you mean about a custom converter?

Comment: It's a Web.Api feature to allow custom transformation. You can check it on Microsoft documentation. The easiest way would be to accept a string though and convert it (see my extended answer).

Comment: @MUTIJIMA as you said, that's a duration format. TimeSpan can't parse durations. If you want richer time support (including IANA timezone support), you should consider using NodaTime